# Create IplImage with stride in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV bindings for Python. I would like to create an `IplImage` object from a buffer with a certain stride, which I cannot change without impacting on other components of my program. With the underlying C structure supports striding (which is called `widthStep`), the only Python constructor I could find (`cv.CreateImage`) doesn't support setting it.

Is there any way to set `widthStep`?

Thanks.

Comment: please, no. IplImages died in 2010. stick with cv2 and numpy images. PLEASE! and avoid the old cv module in general. it won't be there in the next opencv version.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes switching from a major version to another is not really immediate. If I could find a workaround for my current code, it would be much easier for me.

Comment: That being said; Mat objects work way, waaaay better. Same goes for numpy arrays/images. Not alone should you upgrade, but it will also make future development much easier.